# Autocomplete: from pure JS to ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an auto-complete, right now I have it in pure JS

[here I have this example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/qo9yzj3r/)

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="changeInput(this.value)">

<div id="result"></div>
```

the js part

```
var people = ['Steven', 'Sean', 'Stefan', 'Sam', 'Nathan'];

function matchPeople(input) {
  var reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
  return people.filter(function(person) {
    if (person.match(reg)) {
      return person;
    }
  });
}

function changeInput(val) {
  var autoCompleteResult = matchPeople(val);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = autoCompleteResult;
}
```

but I need to translate it to ReactJS, and I am not getting good results

```
let people = ['Steven', 'Sean', 'Stefan', 'Sam', 'Nathan'];

class Login extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <Grid>
          <input type="text" onkeyup={this._changeInput(this.value)} />
          <div id="result"></div>
      </Grid>
    );
  }

  _matchPeople = (input) => {
    var reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
    return people.filter(function(person) {
      if (person.match(reg)) {
        return person;
      }
    });
  }

  _changeInput = (val) => {
    var autoCompleteResult = this._matchPeople(val);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = autoCompleteResult;
  }  

}
```

Error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first render, the `input` doesn't have value so it will be undefined. To solve the problem, you should create a state in getInitialState `{value : ''}` and in the `input` tag , assign the state to value attribute `value={this.state.value}`. Here is how adapt to your code:

```
class Login extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super(props);
     this.state = {value : '', result : ''};

  }     

  render () {
    return (
      <Grid>
          <input type="text" onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)} onKeyUp={this._changeInput.bind(this)} value={this.state.value} />
          <div id="result">{this.state.result}</div>
      </Grid>
    );
  }

  _matchPeople = (input) => {
    var reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
    return people.filter(function(person) {
      if (person.match(reg)) {
        return person;
      }
    });
  }

  _changeInput() {
    var autoCompleteResult = this._matchPeople(this.state.value);
    this.setState({result : autoCompleteResult})
  }  

  _onChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({value: event.target.value})
   }

}
```

It will be better if you track value change in `onChange` event of the input as well.

Comment: but, how do I adapt it to my code ? I mean, what about my other functions ?

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clear for you. Try it :)

Comment: Now I am getting an issue with this `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = autoCompleteResult;` says innerHTML of unidefined. Which method should I use there ?

Comment: because the content of `result` div is changed frequently, it should be a state as well. I edited it the code again. try it

Comment: Now I can't type anything in the input. Actually is asking to change `getInitialState(){}` so I did `constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = {value : ''}; }`

Comment: Oh ! I need you bind intance methods as well : `constructor{props}(....this. _changeInput = this. _changeInput.bind(this);  _onChange...the same`

Comment: it is so weird. I did everything and still can't type

Comment: it was actually because I had `onchange` instead of `onChange`, anyways, still can't see anything. It is not working.

Comment: hmmm. it should work. could you check `console.log(event)` in `_onChange` to see if the method is executed.

Comment: I did `console.log` in `onChange` and `event SyntheticEvent {dispatchConfig: Object, dispatchMarker: ".0.1.0.0.0.0", nativeEvent: Event, type: "input", target: input…}`

Comment: I did `console.log` in the other functions also, and I can't see anything in the console, is like if those functions are not being called.

Comment: do you have `value={this.state.value}` in the input tag. if you do, but it still doesn't work. Sorry ! I can't help you . :(

Comment: Okie. I change the bind method the input tag. Change `onchange` into `onChange` and `onkeyup` into `onKeyUp` as well. Take a look. This is the last chance. That's what I can do. Hope it work :)